# I/O Error with open()

Tags: python, linux, io, permissions

```
class NewTab():
    def __init__(self, song_title, artist_name):
        self.song_title  = song_title
        self.artist_name = artist_name
        name1    = self.artist_name + "_" + self.song_title
        name2    = name1.replace(" ", "")
        new_file = open("~/Documents/"+name2+".txt", "a+")

tab = NewTab(raw_input("Song Title: "), raw_input("Artist Name: "))
```

---

I am trying to create a new file (assuming it doesn't already exist) whose name is generated from two strings of User input. For example:

```
"Song Title: "  >> Personal Jesus
"Artist Name: " >> Depeche Mode
```

should result in creating: `~/Documents/DepecheMode_PersonalJesus.txt`

---

Unfortunately I am always left with:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or director: '~/Documents/DepecheMode_PersonalJesus.txt'
```

I have tried different open() modes, such as `"w"`, `"w+"` and `"r+"` to no avail.
I have also tried placing `name1`, `name2`, and `new_file` into a method outside of `__init__` like so:

```
    def create_new(self):
        name1    = self.artist_name + "_" + self.song_title
        name2    = name1.replace(" ", "")
        new_file = open("~/Documents/"+name2+".txt", "a+")

tab.create_new()
```

but this results in the exact same Error.

I have set my `/Documents` folder Permissions (Owner, Group, Others) to `Create and delete files`.

Beyond that, I am at a complete loss as to why I cannot create this file. It is clearly structuring the file name and directory the way that I want it, so why won't it go ahead and create the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use os.path.expanduser() function to get a full valid path with "~" resolved and pass this to open()

```
    new_file = open(os.path.expanduser("~/Documents/")+name2+".txt", "a+")
```

this will resolve "~" to something like /home/user and join it with the rest of the path elements.

Comment: +1 The `~` is a shortcut implemented by the shell, so you need something like `os.path.expanduser` to produce the real path in Python.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't necessarily need to use "a+" then having "wb" as a second parameter will automatically open a file.

```
foo = open("bar", "wb")
```

Comment: The only problem is that if you open an existing file (which has something in it) with 'wb' then it will erase everything.